# Yii migrate 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'karyawan/create' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: yii2, migrate

hello advanced im using yii2 advanced, im on progress RBAC implementation

i create new roles like this

```
public function up()
    {
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;    
        // karyawan index
        $karyawanindex = $auth->createPermission('karyawan/index');
        $karyawanindex->description = 'karyawan index';
        $auth->add($karyawanindex);
        // karyawan create
        $karyawancreate = $auth->createPermission('karyawan/create');
        $karyawancreate->description = 'karyawan create';
        $auth->add($karyawancreate);    
        // karyawan view
        $karyawanview = $auth->createPermission('karyawan/view');
        $karyawanview->description = 'karyawan view';
        $auth->add($karyawanview);
        // karyawan update
        $karyawanupdate = $auth->createPermission('karyawan/update');
        $karyawanupdate->description = 'karyawan update';
        $auth->add($karyawanupdate);
        // karyawan delete
        $karyawandelete = $auth->createPermission('karyawan/delete');
        $karyawandelete->description = 'karyawan delete';
        $auth->add($karyawandelete);
        // agive role permission
        $prouser = $auth->createRole('prouser');
        $auth->add($prouser);
        $auth->addChild($prouser, $karyawancreate);
        $auth->addChild($prouser, $karyawanindex);
        $auth->addChild($prouser, $karyawanupdate);
        $auth->addChild($prouser, $karyawanview);
        $auth->addChild($prouser, $karyawandelete);
       //give role permission
        $basicuser = $auth->createRole('basicuser');
        $auth->add($basicuser);
        $auth->addChild($basicuser, $karyawanindex);
        $auth->addChild($basicuser, $karyawanview);
        //assign user.
        $auth->assign($prouser, 1);
        $auth->assign($basicuser, 2);
    }
```

next step is migrate for implementation but i got error like this

> ```
> Exception 'yii\db\IntegrityException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> ```
>
> 'karyawan/index' for key 'PRIMARY'
>       The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `auth_item` (`name`, `type`, `description`, `rule_name`, `data`, `created_at`,
>   `updated_at`) VALUES ('karyawan/index', 2, 'karyawan index', NULL,
>   NULL, 1513069774, 1513069774)'
>
> ```
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Schema.php:595
>
> Error Info:
> Array
> (
>     [0] => 23000
>     [1] => 1062
>     [2] => Duplicate entry 'karyawan/index' for key 'PRIMARY'
> )
>
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php(1004):
> ```
>
> yii\db\Schema->convertException(Object(PDOException), 'INSERT INTO
>   `au...')
>       #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\rbac\DbManager.php(283):
>   yii\db\Command->execute()
>       #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\rbac\BaseManager.php(130):
>   yii\rbac\DbManager->addItem(Object(yii\rbac\Permission))
>       #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\console\migrations\m171212_062531_init_rbac.php(20):
>   yii\rbac\BaseManager->add(Object(yii\rbac\Permission))
>       #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController.php(725):
>   m171212_062531_init_rbac->up()
>       #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController.php(199):
>   yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->migrateUp('m171212_062531_...')
>       #6 [internal function]: yii\console\controllers\BaseMigrateController->actionUp(0)
>       #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>       #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(157):
>   yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
>       #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Controller.php(135):
>   yii\base\Controller->runAction('', Array)
>       #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528):
>   yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
>       #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(180):
>   yii\base\Module->runAction('migrate', Array)
>       #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(147):
>   yii\console\Application->runAction('migrate', Array)
>       #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386):
>   yii\console\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
>       #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\yii(27): yii\base\Application->run()
>       #15 {main}

i appreciate any solution

Comment: What's your problem? You have duplicate key, so check if exist or remove auth_item before add it.

Comment: i already remove auth_item where the errors exist, and now i got this following error Undefined variable: author is there something wrong on my coding?

Comment: You have to remove karyawan/index key from the table of your database, this error says: 'Hey , you have just save this key on the db and it can be duplicate beacuse it is a primary key'